# Data edition on grid using rowEditing plugin does not work

Tags: extjs

I'm developing an application using Ext Js and I have a problem. I'm using a RowEditing plugin to edit my rows, also the user is able to add dinamically columns and rows in a grid. However, when the user edit the row, only the first column, which is Data Type column, accept and makes visible the edition, the remainder accept the edition but does not makes visible the data, as shown below.

Before edit:

[image]

After edit, and click on update button:

As you can see the data on the remainder columns does not appear.

[image]

My code is shown below:

```
var store = Ext.getStore('StoreTemp');
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing');
var contador = 1;
var contadorLinhas = 0;
Ext.define('Grid', {
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
title: 'Grid',
store: 'StoreTemp',
columns: [ 
        {
         xtype: 'rownumberer',
     },{    
         header : "Data Type",
         dataIndex : 'nome',
         flex : 1,
         editor:'textfield'
     }],            
dockedItems : [ {
    xtype : 'toolbar',
    items : [ {
        xtype: 'button',
        tooltip: 'Click here to set data type on axis Y',
        id : 'buttonTipoDado',
        icon : Webapp.icon('edit.png'),
        iconAlign : 'top',
        handler : function() {
            var gridView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1];
            Ext.Msg.prompt('Alert', 'Insert data type on axis Y', function(
                    btn, text) {
                if (btn == 'ok') {
                    gridView.getView().getHeaderAtIndex(1).setText(text);
                    var botao = Ext.getCmp('buttonTipoDado');
                    botao.setDisabled(true);
                } else {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Alert', 'Insert a type!');
                }
                gridView.getView().refresh();
            });
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        icon : Webapp.icon('add1.png'),
        iconAlign : 'top',
        handler : function() {
            var gridView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1];
            grid = gridView.headerCt;
            if(grid.getGridColumns().length >= 1){
                var column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {dataIndex: 'column', text : contador, editor: {xtype: 'textfield', flex: 0.5, editable: true}});
                grid.insert(gridView.columns.length, column);
                gridView.getView().refresh();
                var botao = Ext.getCmp('buttonRemoverColuna');
                botao.setDisabled(false);
            }
            contador++;
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        icon : Webapp.icon('cancel.png'),
        iconAlign : 'top',
        id : 'buttonRemoverColuna',
        handler : function() {
            var gridView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1];
            gridView = gridView.headerCt;
            var botao = Ext.getCmp('buttonRemoverColuna');
            console.log(gridView.getGridColumns().length);
            if(gridView.getGridColumns().length == 2){
                console.log(gridView.getGridColumns().length);
                botao.setDisabled(true);    
                contador = 1;
            }
            else{
                gridView = gridView.remove(gridView.getGridColumns().length - 1);               
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        icon : Webapp.icon('add1.png'),
        iconAlign : 'top',
        handler: function(){
            var gridView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1];
            store.insert(contadorLinhas, new Ext.create('model'));
            rowEditing.startEdit(0, 0); 
            contadorLinhas++;
            gridView.getView().refresh();
            if(contadorLinhas > 0){
                botao = Ext.getCmp('buttonRemoverLinha'),
                botao.setDisabled(false);
            }
        }   
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        icon : Webapp.icon('cancel.png'),
        iconAlign : 'top',
        id: 'buttonRemoverLinha',
        handler: function(botao){
            store.removeAt(contadorLinhas - 1);
            contadorLinhas--;
            if(contadorLinhas == 0){
                botao.setDisabled(true);
            }
        }   
    }]
} ],
plugins : [ rowEditing ]

});

Ext.define('model', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : [ {
    name : 'id',
    type : 'long'
}, {
    name : 'nome',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name : 'column',
    type : 'array'
} ]
});
```

Can anyone provide me a insight?? Thanks.

Comment: Well, how do you define columns 2, 3 etc?

Comment: columns are being added dinamically!

var column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', {text : contador, editor: {xtype: 'textfield', flex: 0.5, editable: true}});
grid.insert(gridView.columns.length, column);

Comment: There you go. How do you tie new columns to the data in your model? Where is dataIndex field?

Comment: It worked, but have a another problem, I am going to post a screen below!

Comment: Please update the post with changes you've made

Comment: Done, you can see the changes. In this link if you prefer, you can see what is happening: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dPTA5.jpg

Comment: dataIndex should be different for each column. It should corresponds to the field in your model you want to display/edit. And you're using same value for all of them

Comment: Yes, I understood, but how can I set a different dataIndex for each column added, whereas the in the model there is just one field corresponding to the dataIndex column ???

Comment: What do you mean? Please include model code into your question. Do you also dynamically change model?

Comment: Ok, I already posted my model code, check.

Comment: I don't think ExtJs has data type `array`. Are you sure about this?

Comment: I'm going to check this.